# Make it possible for localized sites to correctly translate privileges on the pages, which can't be accessed by a member with low reputation

Tags: feature-request, privileges, localization, russian-stackoverflow

As we have discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336735/260198), it's OK for English sites in the SE network to place dots and commas inside quotes, because it's correct in US English, and in the interface US English is used.

But for Russian, it's incorrect. Commas and dots should be outside the quotes.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tools

> [image: Moderator tools page]

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/site-analytics

> [image: Site analytics page]

The text **access to site analytics** is translated, as you can see, but the quotes and dot are hardcoded, so we don't have the ability to fix it.

Could you change that, so we will be able to correctly localize it?

Comment: It's also worth noting that having the dot outside of a quote is also acceptable in (non-formal) American English (and is in fact the preferred way in British English), so my opinion is to have it outside the quote on all sites, including English ones.

Comment: @SonictheReinstateMonica-hog You would need to bring this up in the link discussion about the English version of this sentence.